# Generate CSRF token for Non-Symfony forms hosted on another site

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, csrf, csrf-protection

OK, so what I'm trying to do may seem like a cross-site attack - defeating the very purpose of CSRF tokens, but here is the need: I have a Symfony app site (app.timo.in) and the plain-PHP homepage web-app (www.timo.in). I wish to allow registered visitors to login from the homepage.

**INFO**: The app & homepage are on the same domain (timo.in)

A possible option is to generate some other token based on a sharedSecret that both sides can understand. I do not want that the token to expire too soon. One advantage I have is that the login form opens in a modal, so a fresh token can be generated each time, with a short validity.
What other parameters do I need to make it secure?
If I include session ID, will both sites understand it?

**ALERT**: I need some sort of CSRF protection, so do not suggest disabling it on the Symfony App's Login page :)

Comment: So what now: You don't want to disable it, or you want to disable it?

Comment: I clarified :) I need CSRF protection. I didn't want fellows to suggest disabling SF token altogether.

Comment: What is your CSRF protection protecting against?

Comment: Some random site trying to post login requests to my app. I can check the HTTP referrer, but not sure that it can't be faked.